# How to avoid LEDs Fluickring?

Tags: filter, camera, led, pwm, rc

I am Using TPS61197DR constant current driver for LEDs Ring. By changing the PWM Duty Cycle to TPS driver the brightness are varied. but the Problem is Fluckring the Fluckring is Observed in Camera. I want to avoid fluckring of these LEDs. How I can do it?

Can I use the Low Pass RC filter to make PWM Signal DC Signal with opamp or transistor to amplify the output DC Signal?